# How to get third occurence of a class in jquery and add another class to it

Tags: jquery, aem

I have an requirement to get the third occurence of a class name

The class name is `coral-buttongroup.rte-toolbar`. How can i get the third occurence of this class and then append something to this.

I have tried with

```
$('.coral-buttongroup.rte-toolbar').eq(2).append('<button  class="desc-count"></button>');
```

But this isn't working.

Comment: Have you tried $(‘.coral-buttongroup.rte-toolbar’)[2] ?

Comment: If that selector is not working, you need to verify that it is accurate, as your syntax looks to be valid.  `eq(2).append('stuff')` would get the third element, as a jQuery object, of the result stack (since it's offset 0), and append whatever to it.

Comment: @muka.gergely `[2]` would do the same thing as `eq(2)` except it will return a raw DOM Element, so they'd have to wrap it in `$()` to use append.  So effectively there is no difference between the two, while `[]` would causes more work to be done

Comment: i have tried with $(‘.coral-buttongroup.rte-toolbar’)[2] it gives the result as undefined @muka.gergely

Comment: If the array syntax gives you undefined, then either your selector isn’t correct or there’s no third element of that array :)

Comment: This is what I have tried $('.coral-buttongroup.rte-toolbar').eq(2).append('<button>class="count-label"</button>')

Comment: And that works assuming you have loaded jQuery, have the code after the elements exists

Comment: Have you tried listing all elements in the console with “each”? That could show whether there are at least three elements in that object or the selector is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works

- You had nested double quotes, but you fixed that
- You need to load jQuery
- Your code has to wait until the elements exist

```js
$(function() {
  $('.coral-buttongroup.rte-toolbar').eq(2)
    .append('<button  class="desc-count">Click</button>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="coral-buttongroup rte-toolbar">1</div>
<div class="coral-buttongroup rte-toolbar">2</div>
<div class="coral-buttongroup rte-toolbar">3</div>
<div class="coral-buttongroup rte-toolbar">4</div>
```